# How can I get hold of my many to many relationships as a class file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

Many to many there I must have a table that is built in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

But as soon as I run this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=tcp:xxxx,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

then the table does not appear at all. Which means that I will in no way only work with the table at all.

The purpose is: a user can be assigned to many companies and a company can have many users.

[image]

It is so that my `userCompanies` do not appear as a class file that allows me to work with it at all.

What should I do to make my `userCompanies` appear?

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/define-a-many-to-many-relationship-and-many-to-many-relationship-properties?view=sql-server-2017&fbclid=IwAR3ohc6D9kgdvLeGAZHwSemWMXlfmcmLVzcAKhEYRs3Hk5zMxtElQAJl1A8)

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework does not need to use Bridge Tables on many to many realationships.

You do not need to use bridge table and you do not need to have concern about it as well.

This is not disadvantage and you can do any operation without having it.

Just a simple Query example would be:

```
dbContext.Company.Where(c => c.Location == "Cyprus" && c.Users.Any(u => u.Age > 30))
    .Select(c => c.FullName).ToList();
```

Edit:

```
var company = dbContext.Company.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 45);
company.Users.Add(yourUserClass);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yeah okay. But how do you want to put it into the database at UserCompanies?